# Access private base class

Tags: c++

Can the derived class access the public member of its private base class

```
class book {
public:
void read ();
void show ();
};
class science: private book
{
public:
void readbook ();
void showbook ();
};


}
```

Can the object of science class access the public of book class which is private base class.

Comment: Have you **tried**?

Comment: Yes. Private base class means the specialization has private access to the public methods of the base class.

Comment: You know, normally "try it" could be confusing. But in this case, I concur with PasserBy. Why didn't you try *before* asking?

Comment: My computer is not working I'm just reading through a book

Answer (score 0):

you can not call book methods directly from an object of the science class.

```
science s;
s.read();
```

won't work
You can only access the book methods from insight the science class. For example a method in the science class that calls the now private methods from the book class.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to remember if you can access base class functions/members is to see the type of inheritance used.

#### Public inheritance

Every public member/function of the base class remains public in the derived class.

#### Protected inheritance

Every public member/function of the base class becomes protected in the derived class.

#### Private inheritance

Both public and protected members/functions in the base class become private in the derived class.

However it's still possible to expose the interface of private base class by writting a using declaration.

```
class book
{
  public:
  void show();
};
class science : private book
{
  public:
  void showscience();
  using book::show;
}
```

Now you can call book::show through a science object

```
science s;
s.show();
```